# get data from a model that is relationed through a child table laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I have a table `Order` an order may have many `Order_details` but every order detail only belongs to a single order. I have another table called `Professionals` every order detail may have many professionals and professionals may have many order_details so I have a pivot table `order_detail_professional`.

```
|Orders|  |order_details| |order_detail_professional| |professionals|
-------  --------------    -------------------------  ---------------
| id  |  |     id     |   |    order_detail_id      | |    id       |
          ------------    |    professional_id      |
         |  order_id  |
```

As you can see `professionals` are related to `orders` but no in a direct way, So i don't know how to get orders from a specific professional.

This are the relationships

```
Order.php
```

```
    public function order_details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class);
    }
```

```
OrderDetail.php
```

```
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

     public function professionals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Professional::class);
    }
```

```
Professionals.php
```

```
     public function order_details()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OrderDetail::class);
    }
```

Any tips on how can I get `Orders` from a specific `Professional`?

Comment: You mean how to build a query from scratch, or with a `Professional` model already in a variable?

Comment: @AugustoMoura I just need to build a eloquent query to get the `Orders` info that are related to a specific professional (logged one for example) it doesn't matter if its with one or another way

Answer (score 0):

Chaining `whereHas`:

```php
$orders = Order::whereHas('order_details', function($orderDetails) use($professionalId){
   $orderDetails->whereHas('professionals', function($professionals) use($professionalId){
      $professionals->where('professionals.id', $professionalId);
   });
})->get();
```

Using nested eager loading and then mapping (in this example, with higher order message):

```php
$orders = Professionals::with('order_details.order')->find($professionalId)
   ->map->getRelationValue('order');
```